# Write a file by batch using Java call

Tags: java, batch-file, java-io

I am developing a application program in which I need to write a file using batch command below:

**[example.bat]**

`date >> a.txt`

When I am running this batch file normally it creates a file a.txt in my current working directory, but when I am calling it from Java application it neither creates file a.txt nor write.

**[Main.java]**

```
File startbat = new File("./example.bat");
Desktop.getDesktop().open(startbat);
```

When I am running my Java file it execute the batch file but no write operations are being done but it should be done.

Comment: It's cmd, not cwd.

Comment: @SteveFest it's cwd = Current Working Directory

Comment: Nvm. Oh.. I got mistaken, because we usually use `cd` instead of `cwd` in topics about batch file, but you are correct since CD and cwd can be different.

Comment: You need to show the entire code section that attempts to execute the batch file, including any enclosing `try`-`catch` blocks.  Show the whole method.  Otherwise your question is off-topic.  See [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exploring the things I found that the Java machine doesn't allow to write a third file from native process. This means you can't write a file by process that is invoked by Java machine. However if you want to follow the above the task you may go like:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("*batcommand*");
Scanner sa = new Scanner(p.getInputStream());
String output = sa.nextLine();
```

Thanks for your valuable answers.